# distribute a vector over list of lists in R

Tags: r

I am trying to populate a list of lists in R. I have a vector of names and a corresponding vector of values as below:

```
lnames <- c("tic", "tac", "toe")
lvals <- c("one", "two", "three")
foo <- vector(mode="list", length=length(lnames))
names(foo) <- lnames
$tic
NULL

$tac
NULL

$toe
NULL
```

I am able to successfully name the list of list with the `lnames` vector. How can I populate the lists inside foo without using a `for` loop or manual assignment?
Expected output:

```
> foo
$tic
[1] "one"

$tac
[1] "two"

$toe
[1] "three"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use :

```
foo[] <- as.list(lvals)
foo
#$one
#[1] "one"

#$two
#[1] "two"

#$three
#[1] "three"
```

Or you can also assign name and values together :

```
setNames(as.list(lvals), foo)
```

Comment: the first solution works better. After the ```as.list(lvals)``` I do ```names(foo) <- lnames``` and I get the result I want